# Dev Express GridView: I want to obtain the row and column of clicked cell - or the headings of row and column

Tags: jquery, gridview, devexpress

I have ben trying this with jQuery and many other approaches.

First, I call a function:

```
ClientSideEvents  RowClick="function(s, e) { OnGridFocusedRowChanged(); }"
```

This has worked to get me to the routine that I use to redirect to another ASPX.

(I am game to use code behind, but I have done something like this before using jQuery and the ASP.net Gridview.)

```
   function OnGridFocusedRowChanged() {
        cell = document.getElementById('<%=ASPxGridView1.ClientID%>')
        alert(cell);  ????
        ViewName = aspxcboDashboard_IN.GetText();
        window.location.href = "Drills.aspx?ViewName=" + ViewName + "&ViewRow=test" + "&ViewCol=test"; 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what part of your code fails, but if you can't fetch grid, use [ClientInstanceName](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_ClientInstanceNametopic) attribute.
E.g. set ClientInstanceName to grid1 and fetch grid as any other global variable:  `window.grid1`, `window["grid1"]` or just `grid1`.